# Sprite kit physics in endless runner game?

Tags: cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, game-physics

How would I use sprite kit physics in my endless runner game?

An endless runner fakes motion by keeping the player stationary but moving the background and all the other objects by a set speed.

BUT, I want to simulate physics.

What if I let my player move with the physics engine, move the background by the displacement of the player from the original position, and then move the player back to it's original position?

Would this be smooth and look good?  If so, then what methods of sprite kit do I use so no visual errors show to the user.

What's the proper solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to center the scene on a node. The best way to learn how to do so is to go ahead and visit the [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html) (go to section titled 'Centering Scene on a Node'), but if you encounter any problems with the implementation let us know!

In case you're wondering how it works, the background stays stationary (unless you want parallax scrolling), while the character moves. However, every frame the camera 'follows' a player, meaning wherever you moved your player with the physics, the screen will follow and keep the character at the center.

*Edit*

Here is the code I use in one of my games to center on the sprite (which is a plane controlled by buttons):

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics {

... #Code here to simulate plane movement and such

SKNode *camera = [self childNodeWithName:@"//camera"];
SKNode *player = [self childNodeWithName:@"//sprite"];

if (player.position.y >= 0) camera.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x, player.position.y);
else camera.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x, 0);

[self centerOnNode:camera];

if (velocity>1){
    self.directionMeter.zRotation = -M_PI/2 + mdirectionOfTravel;
}
}

-(void)centerOnNode:(SKNode *)node {
CGPoint cameraPositionInScene = [node.scene convertPoint:node.position fromNode:node.parent];

node.parent.position = CGPointMake(node.parent.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, node.parent.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y);
}
```

Basically, when the player is above a certain position, I move the camera up with the player. When the player moves anywhere on the x-axis, the camera always moves with them. I have contact detection to find where the player hits the ground (and thus loses), and the background color (the sky) changes according to the altitude of the plane (the higher the plane, the darker the blue).

Comment: But I thought with an endless runner, the background has to be moving and the player has to be stationary. Because the x position will go so far and the game will crash because of the memory problems. Googling "Endless runner sprite kit" shows tutorials giving parallax backgrounds.

Comment: I have made a game before that is very similar to 'Learn to Fly'. By using the centering scene method, I have attained distances of over 1,000,000,000,000 using unsigned long integers without any memory problems. If you would like the character to move both vertically and horizontally with the background animating, imaging the amount of processing you would need if your character would attain a high velocity. You would have to manage the displacement and memory allocation to each background tile (you'd probably need a tile map engine). Using advanced scene processing is more efficient.

Comment: Oh is the game available on the appstore? I'm kinda confused on what you're saying. So instead of an endless runner, I create a very big world and just run physics in it and let the camera follow the player. But like an endless runner I would repeat pooled assets like the background and obstacles to use memory properly. Is that a correct assesment?

Comment: Your approach will vary with respect to your necessities. So far, i'm providing you with methods to achieve what you stated you want. You can try working with a tile map, or center the camera on the node. As far as I know, these are the two best approaches to your specifications and no one can decide which is better but you. (I took down my app from the store for now, managing a couple critical updates but can pm you a video or such).

Comment: By repeating pooled assets, what do you mean? In my game (as in Learn to Fly), I spawn clouds using an algorithm to place it in the direction i'm traveling in. That way it appears as if the clouds are in the background, but I'm really reusing the same couple images with different sizes. Once again, everything is based on your specs.

Comment: let's say the player has already gotten past the clouds, they're out of the screen and the player will never encounter them again. What happens to them? Do I just leave them behind to the left of the world rotting? Or do I move them in front of the player to be used again?

Comment: And I'll have a seamless tiled background, do I need to move these backgrounds in front once they're out of sight? Or can I leave them? If I leave them, how small do they have to be before the app's frame rates drop? And how do I know to create or move to front the next background? How would I know where to place it? If you're too busy to answer my quedtions, you could pm me the code in your game for the backgrounds.

Comment: You keep track of all clouds, and if they are, for example, more than 1000 points away, then you despawn them and remove from memory. Tile maps are all abount experimenting, i'm afraid you will need to try that for yourself. Sure, i'll pm you when I get home today.

Comment: Well, looks like there is no way to pm (sorry). I'll attach my code to my answer.